# Failed to apply plugin Android Studio

Tags: android, bintray

I am trying to import ExoPlayer library into my Android Studio project. I have tryed few times with several methods ( importing direct with GRADLE ), import as module, copy paste it, I get the same error:

```
Error:(15) A problem occurred evaluating project ':..:ExoPlayer:library'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'bintray-release']
   > Plugin with id 'bintray-release' not found.
```

In library gradle I found the apply plugin line:

```
apply plugin: 'bintray-release'
```

After Searching the library and apply it to dependencies I still got the error:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.2.10'
}
```

Any Ideea how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like gradle could not find this plugin in all specified repositories. ExoPlayer specifies buildscript repositories in the root project, so that's  what you should do too.

In your root `build.gradle` make sure `buildscript` section contains `jcenter()` repository and `'andcom.novoda:bintray-release:0.2.7'` classpath:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...... <- whatever you have now
        jcenter() <- make sure this one is there
    }
    dependencies {
        ...... <- whaterver you have now
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.2.7' <- make sure this one is there
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, but is stupid, if I have in library gradle why should I have it in the main project gradle, however, good to know, thank you !

Comment: you'r right - this should be in library's gradle config file. Feel free to submit a merge request to ExoPlayer project

Comment: in my case it still gives an error. after putting this line, what should I do?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela maybe you are having another error? What error do you see?

Comment: Sorry It worked, I think there was some unknown issue which got resolved. It working thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. :)

Comment: @PavelDudka please update the answer.. it`s not working.. after add this latest dependency only my problem solved **classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'**

Comment: now i got "Error:(23, 0) Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':..:ExoPlayer:classpath' after it has been resolved." Could sb help me?

Comment: Has been settled. I copied the lib in my project like stated here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WBVsEYg1mg