# Android change build.gradle to import external library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use [MaterialDialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) in my project, but this library doesn't support my Right to Left language and I must edit that. After downloading the project and importing it into current project I get this error when building my project:

```
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.novoda.bintray-release' not found.
```

After many searches on the web I find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29776690/4790312) to resolve this. But that doesn't work for my project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        /* I'm adding this below line */
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.2.7'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have downloaded the actual library and have imported it to Android studio and modified it then you want to add the dependency in your gradle.build (Module:app). The code you are showing is from gradle.build (Project: NameOfYourProject) so I would delete that line you added there.

Go to the build.gradle (Module:app) file which will look something like shown below and add the library as shown.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourappname"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':nameOfTheLibrary')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
}
```

and press the sync button.

Comment: i say this library doesn't support my Right to Left language and I must edit that from source