# How to use ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to use **ExoPlayer** in my app. Could you please tell me which is simplest example? I have tried to do likely https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/ but it's not easy for me. I tried to import `library` as module then i received `bintray-release` error.

Comment: hey refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776690/failed-to-apply-plugin-android-studio) for solution hope it will help you

Comment: the simplest way is just add jcenter to your build gradle repo, then add com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer as dependencies.

Comment: Hmm... i mean has many files in the sample and i don't know what should i use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the main [Readme.md](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer#), you can import ExoPlayer as you will do for any other dependencies :

In your app `build.gradle` > `dependencies` add :

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:rX.X.X'
```

The current version is `r1.5.1` as of October 27, 2015. see [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases).

Comment: Thanks, i'm using compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.1', but i don't know how to add exoplayer into my app and play video on it.

Comment: you will have to dig yourself in https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo

Comment: Yes, my app is playing video with exoplayer now. Anyway many thanks!

Comment: feel free to accept my answer if you think it's a correct answer @NaPro

Comment: Yes, i want to vote your answer but i'm not enough reputation to do that, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but since there are too few simple ExoPlayer tutorials out there, I wrote this up. I recently converted an app I have from using Android's default media player to ExoPlayer. The performance gains are amazing and it works on a wider range of devices. It is a bit more complicated, however.

This example is tailored specifically to playing an http audio stream but by experimenting you can probably adapt it easily to anything else. This example uses the latest v1.xx of ExoPlayer, currently v1.5.11:

First, put this in your build.gradle (Module: app) file, under "dependencies":

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.11'
```

Also your class should implement `ExoPlayer.Listener`:

```
...implements ExoPlayer.Listener
```

Now here's the relevant code to play an http audio stream:

```
    private static final int RENDERER_COUNT = 1; //since we want to render simple audio
    private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE = 64 * 1024; // for http mp3 audio stream use these values
    private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT = 256; // for http mp3 audio steam use these values
    private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;

// for http mp3 audio stream, use these values
    int minBufferMs = 1000;
    int minRebufferMs = 5000;

    // Prepare ExoPlayer
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, minBufferMs, minRebufferMs);

    // String with the url of the stream to play
    String stream_location = "http://audio_stream_url";        
    // Convert String URL to Uri
    Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream_location);

    // Settings for ExoPlayer
    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(ChicagoPoliceRadioService.this, "ExoPlayer_Test");
    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(ChicagoPoliceRadioService.this, null, userAgent);
    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
            streamUri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT);
    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);

    // Attach listener we implemented in this class to this ExoPlayer instance
    exoPlayer.addListener(this);

    // Prepare ExoPlayer
    exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);

    // Set full volume
    exoPlayer.sendMessage(audioRenderer, MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, 1f);

    // Play!
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

There are three callback methods:

```
 @Override
 public void onPlayWhenReadyCommitted() {

    // No idea what would go here, I left it empty

}

// Called when ExoPlayer state changes
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

    // If playbackState equals STATE_READY (4), that means ExoPlayer is set to
    // play and there are no errors
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
        // ExoPlayer prepared and ready, no error
        // Put code here, same as "onPrepared()"
       }
}

// Called on ExoPlayer error
@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
    // ExoPlayer error occurred
    // Put your error code here
}
```

And when you're done playing do the usual:

```
if (exoPlayer != null) {
                exoPlayer.stop();
                exoPlayer.release();
            }
```

NOTE: I'm still not 100% sure about the details of all of the ExoPlayer settings. I've never tried playing video. Note this is for version 1.5.x of ExoPlayer, 2.0 changed a lot and I still haven't figured it out. I do highly recommend this code to anyone who has an app that streams audio from the web as the performance gains are incredible and for my app it fixed an issue with Samsung phones that would only play about 30sec of audio before stopping.

Comment: I am facing issues getting the getDuration() for an AAC file using ExoPlayer. Could you have a look? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777975/not-able-to-get-getduration-for-aac-file-using-exoplayer . Thanks!